# How to ensure mysql starts automatically if server restarts on Ubuntu Server

Tags: mysql, vps, ubuntu, startup

Occasionally for various reasons my webhost 'reboots' my VPS after doing some routine maintenance or upgrades.  However when they do, or if I reboot the server for any reason myself, mysql doesn't restart.

To restart it I need to ssh in and run...

```
service mysql start
```

How can I make it start automatically like the other programs my website depends on to work properly.  Otherwise users of my site see the site down until I can get in and fix it.

Is this an issue with Ubuntu Server or is it my vps host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that line to your `/etc/rc.local` file when the server reboots it will start mysql

Comment: Thanks.  That worked great.  I rebooted manually to test and my website came back up right away...